# fetch specific word or number from url address

Tags: r

I have one link address which looks like this :-

"https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/10651624"
"https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/12488284124""

My out put should look like this :-

```
1065162
12488284124
```

is it possible to do it in R? for multiple link addresses? in loop? like for 10000 links?

Comment: i added answer to question :)

Comment: I like the `basename()` in the linked question. So far I've been using it just for operating with paths. Curious what the edge cases would be.